# Pandas read data with incorrect number of separators

Tags: pandas, csv

I want to read a `csv` file into `Pandas` `DataFrame` and the file contains several rows with an incorrect number of separators. I know that it's possible to skip these rows via setting up `error_bad_line=False`. But I want to read them in this way:

- Correct data: `some text,label`, in this case `1st column` = `some text`, `2nd column` = `label`
- Incorrect data: `some text, another text, again some text,label`, in this case, I want `1st column` = `some text, another text, again some text`, `2nd column` = `label`

Is this possible to handle incorrect data in this way using Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the columns for example:

```
df['some text, another text, again some text'] = (df['some text'] + df['another text'] + df['again some text'])

print(df)
```

which will transform this:

```
some text  another text  again some text  label;;;;;  \

0     ;;;;;           NaN              NaN         NaN   
1     ;;;;;           NaN              NaN         NaN   
2     ;;;;;           NaN              NaN         NaN   
3     ;;;;;           NaN              NaN         NaN   
4     ;;;;;           NaN              NaN         NaN   
5     ;;;;;           NaN              NaN         NaN   
6     ;;;;;           NaN              NaN         NaN
```

Into this:

```
  some text, another text, again some text  
0                                      NaN  
1                                      NaN  
2                                      NaN  
3                                      NaN  
4                                      NaN  
5                                      NaN  
6                                      NaN
```

I didn't filled the rows, so some random ; and NaN appears, but it is separated!

Does anyone have a better approach to this? Thanks